# How to determine whether a list can be found within a nested set that is in list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, set

#### I would like to determine whether a list of strings can be found within a nested set that is in list in python.

For example:

```
list1 = ['cat','dog']

animal = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
color = ['yellow','red','blue','purple','green','orange']
action = ['run','jump','swim','fly']

list2 = [animal,color,action]

result = False

list1 = set(list1)

for type in list2
    if list1.issubset(list2[type])
        result = True

print(result)
```

and the result should be true, but it prints the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

Is there any way to search through the nested list?

Comment: When you do `for type in list2` then `type` is the list itself so you can use `if list1.issubset(type)` (also `type` is probably not a great variable name since it's used by Python). Also, probably easier: `any(list1.issubset(l) for l in list2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for error is because you already accessed the list and passed the list as argument to the list2.

```
for type in list2:
```

The **type** consist of lists of animal, color and action already. If we try to print type we have:

```
for type in list2:
    print(type)
```

Output:

```
['iguana', 'cat', 'spider', 'monkey', 'dog']
['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green', 'orange']
['run', 'jump', 'swim', 'fly']
```

So passing this as argument to list2 i.e., list2[type] is giving the error.

All you need to do is to directly compare the list1 with the type as follows:

```
if list1.issubset(type):
```

Hence, the complete code is:

```
list1 = ['cat','dog']
animal = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
color = ['yellow','red','blue','purple','green','orange']
action = ['run','jump','swim','fly']
list2 = [animal,color,action]
result = False
list1 = set(list1)
for type in list2:
    if list1.issubset(type):
        print(type) # Print the list which is having the subset
        result = True
print(result)
```

It will print the list in which the subset is found and the result as true.

**Note**: This can only work when the list1 is exactly subset in one of the nested list. In case, partial part is in one of the nest while the part part is in the another nest, then you need to flatten the list. One way to do it is:

```
from itertools import chain
flatten=list(chain.from_iterable(list2))
if list1.issubset(flatten):
    result = True
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to print what list it is a part of instead of changing the result to 2?

Comment: I have shown above, just before result=True, ihad printed the list. In short, You can print the list which is having the subset through code:             

        if list1.issubset(type): 
                                          print(type)

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list of lists and then compare the elements in list1 with the flattened one using simple list comprehension.

```
list1 = ['cat','dog']

animal = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
color = ['yellow','red','blue','purple','green','orange']
action = ['run','jump','swim','fly']

list2 = [animal,color,action]

flatlist = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]

result = all(element in flatlist for element in list1) 

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find if `list1` is a subset of a sublist in `list2` you can do:

```
>>> [l for l in list2 if set(list1).issubset(l)]
[['iguana', 'cat', 'spider', 'monkey', 'dog']]
```

Which itself will be `True`

You can also use `any` in the same way:

```
>>> any(set(list1).issubset(l) for l in list2) 
True
```